# Why does this code using pointers not retrieve the value of x using b?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
int x=10,*a=&x;
int *b=(int *)&a;
printf("%d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  ",x,a,*a,b,*b,**b);
return 0;
}
```

In this little program  variable `x` is assigned value `10` and then address of `x` is assigned to pointer variable `a`. Now proper way is `int **b=&a` because `b` should be a pointer to  pointer. But I thought it's ultimately the address which gets stored. So to store address of `a` to an int pointer `b`, I use typecasting `int *b=(int *)&a`. Now address of `a` got stored in `b`. So if I use `*b`, it give identical result as `a`.

But when I extend this further  to `**b`  it doesn't give the same result as `*a` which I expected. In fact it gives an error. `*b` and `a` are same so when i ask to retrieve from this value like `**b` and `*a` this doesn't work. For this I assumed a concept that `*b` and `a` are same in value but they are different in type. The value given by `a` is pointer and value given by `*b` is an integer so `**b` is not possible like `*a`.

But I still think that it should work.

I am using Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 which is a 32 bit compiler. The memory allocated to an `int` and `int *` is the same, that is 4 bytes. And `*b` and `a` have same bit representation also. So when I write `*(*b)` I used same value as in `*(a)`. But what is the preventing factor?  The format is like `*(some bit representation)` and the  bit representation is identical in case of `*b` and `a`. So the value of `x` should be retrieved. Please explain the preventing factor.

Comment: If you want `b` to be an `int*`, then you want to say `int* b = a` so you can access `x` through `*b`.  But if you want `b` to be an `int**` then you can say `int** b = &a` and access `x` through `**b`.  Draw a picture :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*b` is an integer, and you're not allowed to apply the unary `*` to an integer. (How would the compiler know whether you expected the bit pattern to point to an int, char, short, or whatever?) You can cast the integer back to a pointer and then deference it: `*(int*)*b`, which should do what you expect.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to work fine for me, once your variable declarations are cleaned up a bit:

```
int main (){
        int x = 10;
        int* a = &x;
        int** b = &a;
        printf("%d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  ",x,a,*a,b,*b,**b);
        return 0;
}
```

I'd suggest that the problem is that you declared `b` with the wrong type (and then cast `&a` into that type).  It is not an `int*`, it is an `int**`, i.e. a pointer to a pointer to an integer.  You could of course cast `*b` to the desired type in your `printf()` statement, but why not just declare it correctly in the first place?

Here's an ideone example:  http://ideone.com/idwfd

Comment: Actually, he said in the wall-of-text under the code that he already knew that it would work with `int** b`. (I cannot really fault you for missing that, though).

Answer (score 2):

```
int x= 10;
```

[image]

```
int *a = &x;    //address of x is 0x33
```

[image]

```
Int * b = (int *) &a;     //address of a is 0x34
```

[image]

So from the above we have that:

- x  = 10 a  = 33
- *a = 10 b  = 34
- *b = 33
- * (int *) *b = 10
- **b  would result in a compilation error

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what happens here. `a` is a pointer to `int`. We take the address of `a`, which is a pointer to pointer to `int`, cast that to a pointer to `int`, and assign it to `b`.

Then we dereference `b` twice. `b` is a pointer to `int`, so `*b` is an `int`. Then we dereference an `int`. Wait, you can't dereference an `int` - it's not a pointer. And so we enter the twilight zone of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`**b` would point to the correct block of memory, but the compiler doesn't have the proper type information. @Henning says, dereferencing `b` once is an `int` value according to the compiler, and there's no dereference operator for type `int`. That's specifically why the `int**` and its ilk exist: to tell the compiler how many dereferences are possible/necessary.

Out of curiosity is there a reason `int* b = a;` doesn't work, if you do want the value of `x` after one dereference?

Answer (score 0):

```
+----------+    +----------+    +----------+
|    10    |    |  addr_x  |    |  addr_a  |
+----------+    +----------+    +----------+
|    x     |    |    a     |    |    b     |
+----------+    +----------+    +----------+
|  addr_x  |    |  addr_a  |    |  addr_b  |
+----------+    +----+-----+    +----+-----+
  ^  ^               |   ^           | 
  |  +----(*a)-------+   +----(*b)---+
  |                                  |
  +----------------(**b)-------------+
```

The access is like above.

You have told the compiler that the pointer `b` is a pointer to an integer. When you do `*b` it dereferences to an `int` and another indirection is not possible on type of  `int and therefore when you access`b`it as a pointer to a pointer to an integer in (`**b`). It is not allowed. To do so you need to typecast the value of`b` to the correct type and use it.

You want to use the value of `*b` as an address and fetch the int value stored at the address location `*b`. Therefore You want `*b` to be an `int *` which makes `b` an (int **) . Therefore it is best to declare `b` as `int **b;`  . In your case before applying the double indirection typecast `b` to be `int **` and then use double indirection.

```
printf ("%x", **((int **)b));
```

This will interpret the value stored in `b` as a pointer to a pointer to an integer and then fetch the value of `x` as you want.